Moving box plots in pgfplots
LaTeX Output:

Trying to move the box plot B a little bit further to the right and the box plot C a little bit further to the left. How would I go about doing this?
The "coordinate" argument at the end of the addplot function does not seem to do anything.
Remark from @MS-SPO: This code does not compile ...
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows.meta}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 

\begin{axis}[ 
boxplot/draw direction=y, 
boxplot/box extend=0.5, 
xtick={1, 2, 4}, 
xticklabels={A, B, C}, 
ylabel={D ($%$)}, 
ymajorgrids=false, 
xmajorgrids=false, 
ymin=0, 
ymax=35, 
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, 
anchor=north, 
legend columns=-1}, 
width=10cm, 
axis x line*=bottom, a
xis y line*=left, ]

    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=25,
            upper quartile=25.25,
            lower quartile=18.75,
            upper whisker=26,
            lower whisker=18,
        },
        fill=blue!50,
        draw=blue,
    ] coordinates {};

    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=25.5,
            upper quartile=29.25,
            lower quartile=24.25,
            upper whisker=30,
            lower whisker=22,
        },
        fill=red!50,
        draw=red,
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=0,
            upper quartile=0,
            lower quartile=0,
            upper whisker=0,
            lower whisker=0,
        },
    ] coordinates {};

    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=24,
            upper quartile=27.25,
            lower quartile=20.75,
            upper whisker=28,
            lower whisker=20,
        },
        fill=red!50,
        draw=red,
    ] coordinates {};

    \draw[red] (axis cs:2.5,22) -- (axis cs:3.5,20);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,25) -- (axis cs:3.5,21);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,25) -- (axis cs:3.5,24);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,26) -- (axis cs:3.5,24);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,29) -- (axis cs:3.5,27);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,30) -- (axis cs:3.5,28);
    \addplot[
        only marks,
        mark=*,
        mark size=1.5pt,
        color=red,
        ] coordinates {
            (2.5,22)
            (3.5,20)
            (2.5,25)
            (3.5,21)
            (2.5,25)
            (3.5,24)
            (2.5,26)
            (3.5,24)
            (2.5,29)
            (3.5,27)
            (2.5,30)
            (3.5,28)
        };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Remark form @MS-SPO: while this one does:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows.meta}
%
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture} 
%
\begin{axis}[ 
    boxplot/draw direction=y, 
    boxplot/box extend=0.5, 
    xtick={1, 2, 4}, 
    xticklabels={A, B, C}, 
    ylabel={D ($\%$)},      % <<< !!!
    ymajorgrids=false, 
    xmajorgrids=false, 
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=35, 
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.15)}, 
        anchor=north, 
        legend columns=-1}, 
    width=10cm, 
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left, 
]
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=25,
            upper quartile=25.25,
            lower quartile=18.75,
            upper whisker=26,
            lower whisker=18,
        },
        fill=blue!50,
        draw=blue,
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=25.5,
            upper quartile=29.25,
            lower quartile=24.25,
            upper whisker=30,
            lower whisker=22,
        },
        fill=red!50,
        draw=red,
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=0,
            upper quartile=0,
            lower quartile=0,
            upper whisker=0,
            lower whisker=0,
        },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=24,
            upper quartile=27.25,
            lower quartile=20.75,
            upper whisker=28,
            lower whisker=20,
        },
        fill=red!50,
        draw=red,
    ] coordinates {};

    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,22) -- (axis cs:3.5,20);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,25) -- (axis cs:3.5,21);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,25) -- (axis cs:3.5,24);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,26) -- (axis cs:3.5,24);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,29) -- (axis cs:3.5,27);
    \draw[red]  (axis cs:2.5,30) -- (axis cs:3.5,28);
    \addplot[
        only marks,
        mark=*,
        mark size=1.5pt,
        color=red,
        ] coordinates {
            (2.5,22)
            (3.5,20)
            (2.5,25)
            (3.5,21)
            (2.5,25)
            (3.5,24)
            (2.5,26)
            (3.5,24)
            (2.5,29)
            (3.5,27)
            (2.5,30)
            (3.5,28)
        };
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you provide a complete code snipped with a \begin{document} and everything? Also, a picture is worth a thousand words.

Will do! There is a picture link in the code but I will place that outside the code.

Your MWE (Minimal Working Example) is not complete. Please add preamble and end codes lines of your example.

Should be fixed now.

@weekly5112 One of the downsides of using automated drawing schemes is that it can be difficult to go in and adjust the finer details. The boxplot prepared syntax you are using seems to automatically set their spacing and positioning relative to the width (someone correct me if I'm wrong, this is just by observation). Anyways, my suggestion would either be to reposition the coordinates so that they intersect your boxplot appropriately, or if you want the fine control you are asking for, base tikz syntax will 100% work.

Welcome. // It's hard to understand what you want your final diagram look like. Can you please add a sketch about the "shifts to left and right"? Thank you

Thank you so much for the help! I think I have figured it out and I won't require any more help.

Fine :) // Did you consider to answer your question yourself, so you can share your solution with this community? Would be nice, would be interesting. Thank you

Besides the (at the momemt not too clear) shifting-issue, may be you want the arrows a bit differently?

Relevant changes:

deleted the duplicate last \addplot, which just seems to add the arrow tips (badly)
added needed style statements at \begin{tikzpicture}[...
changed the draw option accordingly \draw[lines]  (axis cs:2.5,22) -- (axis cs:3.5,20);
this way all you need to do is adjusting the lines-style and change arrow tips as needed (e.g. use Circle[] from arrows.meta for dot-tips, Chpt. 16.5)

I'm not sure all the lower arrows are correct/as wanted in your posted code ...

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}    % <<< NEW
%
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    lines/.style={red, ->},     % <<< NEW, for the lines
    >={Stealth},                % different arrow tip
 ]
%
\begin{axis}[ 
    boxplot/draw direction=y, 
    boxplot/box extend=0.5, 
    xtick={1, 2, 4}, 
    xticklabels={A, B, C}, 
    ylabel={D ($\%$)},      % <<< !!!
    ymajorgrids=false, 
    xmajorgrids=false, 
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=35, 
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.15)}, 
        anchor=north, 
        legend columns=-1}, 
    width=10cm, 
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
]
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=25,
            upper quartile=25.25,
            lower quartile=18.75,
            upper whisker=26,
            lower whisker=18,
        },
        fill=blue!50,
        draw=blue,
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=25.5,
            upper quartile=29.25,
            lower quartile=24.25,
            upper whisker=30,
            lower whisker=22,
        },
        fill=red!50,
        draw=red,
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=0,
            upper quartile=0,
            lower quartile=0,
            upper whisker=0,
            lower whisker=0,
        },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            median=24,
            upper quartile=27.25,
            lower quartile=20.75,
            upper whisker=28,
            lower whisker=20,
        },
        fill=red!50,
        draw=red,
    ] coordinates {};
    % ~~~ NEW/different ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[lines]  (axis cs:2.5,22) -- (axis cs:3.5,20);
    \draw[lines]  (axis cs:2.5,25) -- (axis cs:3.5,21);
    \draw[lines]  (axis cs:2.5,25) -- (axis cs:3.5,24);
    \draw[lines]  (axis cs:2.5,26) -- (axis cs:3.5,24);
    \draw[lines]  (axis cs:2.5,29) -- (axis cs:3.5,27);
    \draw[lines]  (axis cs:2.5,30) -- (axis cs:3.5,28);

    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

